# My php validation and form to email go straight to my confirmation page

Tags: php

I have a form, php validation, and send to email. My php validation works fine. My send to email works fine. When I use them both together, they work fine until I add   header('Location: http://google.com'); exit(); I am using google.com for because I havent made my confirmation page yet. When I add this line to the php, that's when it goes straight to google.com when I go to my website. Can someone please help? I have been trying to figure out all of this validation and form to email for 2 straight days now, and I cannot figure it out. I know nothing about php. My code is below.

My php:

```
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $email2Err = $commentsErr = "";
$name = $email = $email2 = $comments = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
        if ( ! preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email2"])) {
        $email2Err = "It is required to re-enter your email.";
    } else {
        $email2 = test_input($_POST["email2"]);
        // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
        if ( ! preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email2)) {
            $email2Err = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["comments"])) {
        $commentsErr = "A comment is required.";
    } else {
        $comments = test_input($_POST["comments"]);
        if (preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,\?_/'!£\$%&*()+=\r\n-]+$#", $comments)) {
            // Everything ok. Do nothing and continue 
        } else { 
            $commentsErr = "Message is not in correct format.<br>You can use a-z A-Z 0-9 . , ? _                   / ' ! £ $ % * () + = - Only";  
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['service'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['service'] as $selectedService)
            $selected[$selectedService] = "checked";
    }
}
if (empty($errors)) { 
    $from = "From: Our Site!"; 
    $to = "jasonriseden@yahoo.com"; 
    $subject = "Mr Green Website | Comment from " . $name . "";

    $message = "Message from " . $name . " 
      Email: " . $email . " 
      Comments: " . $comments . "";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Please someone help me. I have no idea what is wrong.

Ok. I did what you told me Barmar. Not sure if I did it right or not. It solved one problem, but another was created.

I started over with the code that validates and sends the form data to my email. Now I just want to add header('Location: http://google.com '); exit();  ....and it work. Can you tell me what to do? I have no idea what php, so the more specific that you can be, the better.

Here is the php:

```
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $email2Err = $commentsErr = "";
$name = $email = $email2 = $comments = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{



 if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
   else
     {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
      {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      }
    }


   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else
     {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
      {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
      }
    }

   if (empty($_POST["email2"]))
     {$email2Err = "It is required to re-enter your email.";}
   else
     {$email2 = test_input($_POST["email2"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email2))
      {
      $email2Err = "Invalid email format"; 
      }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["comments"]))
     {$commentsErr = "A comment is required.";}
   else
     {$comments = test_input($_POST["comments"]);
      if (preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,\?_/'!£\$%&*()+=\r\n-]+$#", $comments)) { 
        // Everything ok. Do nothing and continue 
    } else { 
        $commentsErr = "Message is not in correct format.<br>You can use a-z A-Z 0-9 . , ? _ / ' ! £ $ % * () + = - Only";  
      }
    }
     if (isset($_POST['service']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['service'] as $selectedService)
            $selected[$selectedService] = "checked";
    }

}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}

if (empty($errors)) { 
  $from = "From: Our Site!"; //Site name
  // Change this to your email address you want to form sent to
  $to = "jasonriseden@yahoo.com"; 
  $subject = "Mr Green Website | Comment from " . $name . "";

  $message = "Message from " . $name . " 
  Email: " . $email . " 
  Comments: " . $comments . "";
  mail($to,$subject,$message,$from);

  }
?>
```

Comment: This code is called only after the form is submitted?

Comment: If you know nothing about PHP, start at the very beginning of the script and learn about each word / construct with the help of the PHP manual. If there is a specific word then you have a programming question about, then please ask. But in it's current form, this is really too broad. http://php.net/docs

Comment: Why do you try to send an email when no data has been posted?

Comment: Why don't you do any checks if mail sending has failed or was successful?

Comment: What's your script supposed to do if the browser has automatic redirection disabled?

Comment: Harke, I have no idea to them questions or what you are talking about. I just want this form to work. I'm not trying to learn too much about php yet because it is very hard for me to understand, and takes a lot of time which I don't have right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no variable `$errors`. So `if(empty($errors))` is always true, so it goes into the block that sends email and redirects. This happens even if the user hasn't submitted the form yet -- I'm assuming this code is part of the same script that displays the registration form after the code you posted.

You need to make two changes:

1. The code that sends the email and redirects should be moved inside the first `if` block, after all the validation checks.
2. Instead of `if(empty($error))`, it should check `if($nameErr && $emailErr && $email2Err && $commentsErr)`. Or you should change the validation code to set `$error` whenever it's setting one of these other error message variables.

Comment: I changed the code, I think like you said, but am not sure. Now it goes straight to the confirmation page after I submit the form, and doesnt validate.The new code is below.

Comment: Never mind. I guess I cant post the new code, so you can tell me what is wrong with it. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Post the new code at the end of the question. Add `UPDATE` followed by the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but have a look into [Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). By having seperate functions for each validation and have them throw an exception when something is wrong, your code will be much cleaner and bugs will have much less room to pop up. Bonus points if you put all the validation functions in a class.

Example: (I renamed test_input() to sanitize_input(), because that's what it does)

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    try
    {
        $name = getValidatedName();
        $email = getValidatedEmail();

        // send email with $name and $email
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo '<div class="error">' . $e->getMessage() . '</div>';
    }
}

function getValidatedName()
{
    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
        throw new Exception("Name is required");

    $name = sanitize_input($_POST["name"]);

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name))
        throw new Exception("Only letters and white space allowed");

    return $name;
}

function getValidatedEmail()
{
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
        throw new Exception("Email is required");

    $email = sanitize_input($_POST["email"]);

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // you don't have to reinvent the wheel ;)
        throw new Exception("Invalid email format");

    return $email;
}
```

Comment: Thank you winkbrace. I will try my best to go through and figure out what Exception is, what all of that means, and use it, because I like it much better than what I have. It looks nice, clean, and easier.